# Término en español para "coaching"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Hace tiempo me preguntaba si existiría en español alguna palabra para expresar lo que la voz inglesa *coaching*. Trasladé la pregunta a la RAE y me respondieron lo siguiente:

> La voz inglesa *coach* equivale en esta lengua, como recuerda el *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas*, a ‘entrenador’ o ‘preparador’ y los verbos correspondientes. Del ámbito deportivo, el uso de *coaching* ‘entrenamiento, preparación’ ha pasado al de la psicología empresarial y su uso se documenta en abundantes páginas de Internet, donde viene a definirse como ‘proceso de mejora personalizado’, ‘asesoramiento personalizado para el cambio profesional y para la instrucción de los equipos de trabajo’, ‘proceso de acompañamiento individual destinado a impulsar el desarrollo profesional y personal de los directivos’ o expresiones similares. En estos ámbitos, el equivalente para *coach* en castellano sería más bien *tutor*, *asesor* o *consejero*. Los textos en español emplean los extranjerismos sin proponer una traducción o equivalencia.

De hecho, la RAE ha recogido en su última versión la voz ***[coach](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9VjAC8o)*** como

> 1. m. y f. Persona que asesora a otra para impulsar su desarrollo profesional y personal.

Lo que me lleva a pensar que este término no tiene traducción, dado que la RAE sólo añade términos si no hay alternativas. Y según la respuesta de la RAE, *coaching* se podría adaptar como *asesoría* (o *asesoramiento*), *tutoría* o *consejería*, pero ninguno de estos términos me convence, ya que no recogen todo el significado original. Según el Ngram Viewer, el término *[coaching](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coaching&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccoaching%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcoaching%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCoaching%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCOACHING%3B%2Cc0)* ha despuntado su uso en textos en castellano desde 1980 aproximadamente. Y no parece que nadie le busque una adaptación.

¿Es esto así? ¿No hay ningún término en español que podría usarse?

Comment: Por una parte yo preferiría _tutoría_ o _entrenamiento_  y por otra parte no creo que sea exacto decir que la RAE solo acepta términos cuando no hay alternativa ya que como en este caso aceptaron _coach_ como un sinónimo exacto de _entrenador_ (2. m. y f. Dep. entrenador.)

Comment: @DGaleano en el ámbito deportivo efectivamente hay alternativa. Es en el ámbito del desarrollo personal cuando parece no haberla. En todo caso, al introducir el término en el diccionario tenían que reflejar ambas acepciones.

Comment: La página de la Fundéu al respecto: [«¿Existe alguna traducción de _coach_ en español?»](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/coach-2/).

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Interesante artículo, ¡gracias!

Comment: Charlie, por favor, incluye una frase que muestre cómo quieres usar el término que solicitas.

Answer (score 5):

Yo opino que el coaching es la acción que realizan el coach. Es decir, **Coaching** lo podrías entender mejor como *Entrenamiento* y obvio **coach** deberá ser *Entrenador*. De ahí tendríamos algunas composiciones para diferentes áreas:

**Coaching Ontológico**: Es un *entrenamiento* que está dirigido al "desarrollo de la conciencia" y puede tener dos variantes; Persona y Empresarial.

**Coaching Deportivo**: Es un *entrenamiento* físico dirigido especialmente en el "desarrollo y mantenimiento de los músculos" además del acondicionamiento físico.

Entre muchos otros más tipos de Coaching....

Comment: De acuerdo. Coach = Entrenador, Coaching=Entrenamiento.

Comment: Sin embargo el Entrenamiento tiene una alta connotación física / deportiva / competitiva, cuando el ámbito del que estamos hablando no involucra la preparación concentrada para alto desempeño. Me gusta más Asesor,

Comment: ¿Tambien se puede usar capacitación y capacitador?

Answer (score 3):

Yo propondria mas bien

> ### *Coach*: **Asesor**

Aunque la traduccion directa de *coach* seria por supuesto **entrenador** en el caso de proporcionar consejos y sabiduria sobre todo en los negocios es sinduda el ambito de la ***Asesoria***

entonces:

> *Coaching*: **Asesorar**
>
> *Coach*: **Asesor**
>
> *Coaching Practice*: **Asesoria**

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez para *coach* pudiera funcionar **preceptor** (persona que enseña, esp. como maestro privado), que sugiere respeto y que, como actualmente no se usa casi, no induce a confusión. El único problema que le veo es que no se me ocurre cuál podría ser el verbo correspondiente a *coaching*. "Precepción" suena un poco raro.

Comment: Un término algo arcaico tal vez, pero no te creas que no me mola...

Answer (score 2):

[**Mentor**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OxX3Y1t)

> 1. m. y f. Consejero o guía.

podría valer para *coach*. Pero tiene el mismo problema que la palabra sugerida por @cdlvcdlv (*preceptor*) en que tampoco en este caso hay un buen equivalente para *coaching*.

Answer (score 2):

Un término que conviene considerar es el de dirección (o conducción)
Un coach sería un

> **[director](https://dle.rae.es/director?m=form)**

o sea, aquél que [dirige](https://dle.rae.es/dirigir); por cuanto todas las implicaciones de **coaching**, aparecen incluidas en las acepciones del verbo **[dirigir](https://dle.rae.es/dirigir)** (guiar, encaminar, gobernar, aconsejar, orientar), de acuerdo a la definición de la RAE:

> 1. tr. Enderezar, llevar rectamente algo hacia un término o lugar señalado. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. tr. ***Guiar***, mostrando o dando las señas de un camino.
> 3. tr. Poner a una carta, fardo, caja o cualquier otro bulto las señas que indiquen a dónde y a quién se ha de enviar.
> 4. tr. ***Encaminar*** la intención y las operaciones a determinado fin.
> 5. tr. ***Gobernar***, ***regir***, dar reglas para el manejo de una dependencia, empresa o pretensión.
> 6. tr. ***Aconsejar*** y gobernar la conciencia de alguien.
> 7. tr. ***Orientar***, guiar, aconsejar a quien realiza un trabajo.
> 8. tr. Dedicar una obra de ingenio.
> 9. tr. Aplicar a alguien un dicho o un hecho.
> 10. tr. ***Concertar y marcar la orientación*** artística a los componentes de una orquesta o coro, o a quienes intervienen en una película o espectáculo.

De esa manera, tal como existe decir

> **director, ra artístico, ca**
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que decide la orientación artística y la programación de un teatro, de un festival, etc.

o

> **director, ra de escena**
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que se ocupa de la dirección de todo lo relativo a la representación de una obra teatral, como la interpretación, la ambientación, etc.

e incluso

> **director espiritual**
>
> 1. m. Sacerdote que aconseja en asuntos de conciencia a alguien.

El término es igualmente apropiado para la  "***dirección técnico/deportiva***", o la "***dirección ontológica***"

### PD:

Nótese que el término "coach" proviene de el equivalente nuestro castellano de "coche", por lo que coaching tiene el sentido de conducirlo/guiarlo/manejarlo

Ver esta entrada, con la [definición en el diccionario webster 1913](http://www.websters1913.com/words/Coach) (una joya de diccionario de una sola persona)

Ver también *coach | Origin and meaning of coach by Online Etymology* [https://www.etymonline.com/word/coach]

> coach (n.) 1550s, "large kind of four-wheeled, covered carriage," from Middle French coche (16c.), from German kotsche, from Hungarian kocsi (szekér) "(carriage) of Kocs," village where it was first made. In Hungary, the thing and the name for it date from 15c., and forms are found since 16c. in most European languages (Spanish and Portuguese coche, Italian cocchino, Dutch koets).
> Coach (kōch; 224), n. [F. coche, fr. It. cocchio, dim. of cocca little boat, fr. L. concha mussel, mussel shell, Gr. ?, akin to Skr. çankha. Cf. Conch, Cockboat,
>
> coach (n.) 1550, "gran especie de carruaje cubierto de cuatro ruedas", del francés medio coche (16c.), del alemán kotsche, del húngaro kocsi (szekér) "(carruaje) de Kocs," pueblo donde estaba primero hecho. En Hungría, la cosa y su nombre datan del 15c., Y las formas se encuentran desde el 16c. en la mayoría de los idiomas europeos (coche español y portugués, cocchino italiano, koets holandés).

Answer (score 1):

*Guía espiritual* podría funcionar, aunque dudo que nadie lo tomara en serio.

Comment: Yo te encuentro la razón. Los guías espirituales probablemente se hacen llamar coaching para que los tomen en serio.

Comment: ¿Qué tal _guía_ a secas?