# Extranjerismos vs palabras autóctonas en la RAE

Tags: rae, extranjerismos, dle

Acabo de venir de comer y precisamente me acabo de dar cuenta de lo común que es usar la palabra *tupper* (abreviado de la marca *Tupperware*) para denominar a las fiambreras. De hecho, yo esta última ni la uso, suelo usar más bien el anglicismo y, cuando escribo, la versión adaptada *táper*. Pensando que era cosa mía, lo he buscado y encuentro textos [como este](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1VlAAAAMAAJ&q=%22t%C3%A1per%22&dq=%22t%C3%A1per%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM6oDLns3NAhUEOxQKHfg7AysQ6AEINDAD):

> ...el asador silencioso que repecha como puede esta palermitana y solitaria noche de domingo, que baja hasta la cocina de su casi ex casa y busca el pequeño **táper** donde antes de guardar todas las cosas ha apartado tres cabezas de ajo, ...
>
> (Vicente Muleiro, *La balada del asador*, Ed. Planeta.)

No sé en otros países aparte de España cuál será el uso preferente, si se dice *fiambrera* o *táper*, eso sería otra pregunta. En todo caso, hay que admitir que el término adaptado se está empezando a usar de forma generalizada al menos en un país.

La pregunta que me hago más bien es: la RAE no tiene recogido ni *táper* ni *tupper*, obviamente por existir *fiambrera*, pero **¿ha habido algún caso en el que la RAE haya claudicado e incluido un extranjerismo en el diccionario, a pesar de existir una palabra arraigada en español, por el éxito masivo del extranjerismo sobre el término autóctono?** Estoy hablando de términos que signifiquen exactamente lo mismo, y no inclusiones por significados extendidos, como el caso de [coaching](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17203/12637).

En principio se me ocurrió *fútbol*, que gana a *balompié* por goleada. Pero luego vi que *balompié* no era un término autóctono arraigado, sino [un calco de *football*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4uYBXPz). De hecho en Ngram se ve que ámbos términos empezaron a usarse [al mismo tiempo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=f%C3%BAtbol%2Cbalompi%C3%A9&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cf%C3%BAtbol%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bf%C3%BAtbol%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BF%C3%BAtbol%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BF%C3%9ATBOL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbalompi%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbalompi%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBalompi%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBALOMPI%C3%89%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Interesante artículo introductorio de la propia RAE: [Tratamiento de los extranjerismos](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos). En teoría no existe tal caso, pues o bien se trata de _Extranjerismos superfluos o innecesarios_ o bien _Extranjerismos necesarios o muy extendidos_. Pero claro, es la teoría. En la práctica, los superfluos o innecesarios pueden caer rápidamente en _muy extendidos_.

Comment: El que más odio: [*bluyín*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5hicJzA) (*blue jeans*)

Comment: @Yay me acabas de matar...

Comment: @Yay, según el DPD, en los lugares donde se usa [bluyín](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=bluy%C3%ADn), su uso es exclusivo. Es decir, no había una palabra arraigada que fuera desplazada, sino que directamente se usó desde el principio el término en inglés, por eso se acepta.

Comment: Chatear, a pesar de existir «charlar», «conversar» y «platicar»

Comment: @guifa ¡gracias por tu aportación! En todo caso, _chatear_ implica conversar en un _chat_, es un tipo muy específico de charla. No chateas cuando hablas con otra persona cara a cara.

Comment: Realmente si de verdad la RAE quiere hacer un diccionario que recoja el uso de las palabras no le queda otra que claudicar, les guste o no si la gente usa un extranjerismo desplazando a una palabra "autóctona" en algún momento tendrán que incluirla en su diccionario.

Comment: Para rematar vengo yo a decir que es típico, al menos en mi entorno, llamar "túpers" (ni siquiera tápers, pero eso es otra historia) a los que son de plástico, normalmente de forma aproximadamente cuadrada, mientras que fiambrera "gana" cuando el recipiente es metálico o con forma de maletín.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Respuesta en modo *community wiki*, siéntete libre de ampliar esta respuesta si conoces algún caso similar.**

Partiendo del caso de *[bluyín](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5hicJzA)* (comentado por Yay), buscando en el DPD encuentro que es un término aceptado en determinados lugares donde no existe alternativa. De hecho, en dichos lugares se lleva usando el término desde antes de la adaptación usada en otros sitios, y la RAE no desaconseja expresamente su uso, sino que [lo acepta](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=vaquero). Igualmente, guifa mencionó *[chatear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8f3hn6l%7C8f4VoQ1)*, pero también está [aceptada por la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=chat) al ser un término utilizado para un tipo muy concreto de charla. Sin embargo, PiQ mencionó la palabra *tipear* en su respuesta a otra pregunta y, aunque dijo que dicho término no competía con ningún otro en su lugar de residencia, en este caso la RAE sí que desaconseja explícitamente su uso al existir alternativas autóctonas de uso arraigado. Por tanto, se podría considerar que esa expresión supuso una victoria sobre el término arraigado, al menos en determinados lugares.

Abro pues una lista con esta y otras palabras similares que me ido encontrando y que podrían considerarse como respuestas a esta pregunta.

- ***[Tipear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZoqvKTb)***. Uso [desaconsejado por la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=tipear), en favor de *mecanografiar*, *dactilografiar* o *pasar/escribir a máquina*. Yo añadiría incluso *teclear*.
- ***[Bisnes](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bsoNdx)***. Uso [desaconsejado por la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=business), en favor de *negocio*, palabra arraigada que proviene del latín.
- ***[Táper](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z7mZk4e)***. Como afirma @walen, la RAE acabó aceptando *táper* en el diccionario en su actualización de noviembre de 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Yo me la juego por **sandwich** (desde 1927 en la RAE) y **[sándwich](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XCCgErE)** (con tilde desde 1980 en la RAE).

El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas [recomienda](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=s%C3%A1ndwich) **emparedado**, pero sándwich, directo del inglés, ha llevado la delantera desde 1910:

[image]

Comment: Muy interesante. Según el DPD la palabra _emparedado_ se empezó a usar en el último tercio del siglo XIX, y según el Merriam Webster, el primer uso de _sandwich_ en inglés fue en 1861, poco tiempo antes. Resulta curioso ver en el gráfico cómo las dos opciones comenzaron a usarse al mismo tiempo en español (apostaría a que antes de 1900 la palabra _emparedado_ se usaba mayoritariamente con otro sentido).

Comment: Por cierto, me ha hecho gracia la definición de _emparedado_ como "porción **pequeña** de jamón u otra vianda, entre dos rebanadas de pan de molde". ¿[Esto](http://cdn.c.photoshelter.com/img-get2/I0000uz1ueTwDy_g/fit=1000x750/Carnegie-Deli-The-Woody-Allen.jpg) se entiende por "pequeña"? (He tenido ocasión de degustar ese sándwich en el Carnegie Deli de Nueva York, es espectacular.)

Comment: "_No celes del desgraciado / que sin merecer reproche / fue vilmente traicionado / y cambióse en [medianoche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OkGmKdR) / por no ser **emparedado**._" Pedro Muñoz Seca. _La venganza de don Mendo_.

Answer (score 4):

*«(...) la RAE no tiene recogido ni* táper *ni* tupper, *obviamente por existir* fiambrera, *pero ¿ha habido algún caso en el que la RAE haya claudicado e incluido un extranjerismo en el diccionario, a pesar de existir una palabra arraigada en español, por el éxito masivo del extranjerismo sobre el término autóctono?»*

Pues mira, tu pregunta fue premonitoria. Precisamente...

> [**táper**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z7mZk4e)
>   De *Tupperware®*, marca reg.
>
> 1. m. Recipiente de plástico con cierre hermético, que se usa para guardar o llevar alimentos.

... la RAE como dices "claudicó" y aceptó **táper** en su última actualización del DLE (2018).

Answer (score 3):

Pues yo añado [*almazuela*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almazuela), aunque no cumpla exactamente con las condiciones de la pregunta, ya que no es una palabra muy conocida fuera de La Rioja ni su rival está (todavía, pero tiempo al tiempo) en el DLE.

Sin embargo, es una palabra con solera (viene del árabe y está documentada desde el siglo XVII) y, [coincido con Álex Grijelmo](https://books.google.es/books?id=R7_7AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT120&ots=Rk81GkZnAf&dq=almazuela&hl=es&pg=PT119#v=onepage&q=almazuela&f=false), de hermoso sonido, a diferencia de *patchwork*, que es indócil a la pronunciación de un hispanohablante.

Lo triste es que no está incluida en el diccionario y que *patchwork* acabará entrando, tal cual o como "páchguor". Lo mismo da, ¿eh?

Comment: "Ninguno de nuestros poetas pondría _patchwork_ en un verso. Pero cualquier poema se engrandecerá con la palabra _almazuela_." ¡Me ha encantado la frase y tu respuesta! Si bien es cierto que ninguno de los dos términos está en el DRAE, la palabra _almazuela_ es prácticamente desconocida mientras que _patchwork_ no. El extranjerismo frente a la palabra autóctona.

Comment: Aun siendo cuestión de gustos, creo que para cualquiera con un mínimo sentido estético considerará que _almazuela_ suena y se ve escrita mucho mejor que _páchguor_. Sin embargo, _almazuela_ en algún momento también fue un extranjerismo, lo que me lleva a preguntarme ¿Fue _almazuela_ en algún momento algo tan horroroso como _páchguor_? Dicho de otro modo: A base de introducir anglicismos ¿Llegará algún día _páchguor_ a sonar bien a los oídos de un hispanohablante? No son preguntas directas, tan sólo unas reflexiones.

Comment: Hombre, los árabes estuvieron en la península desde el siglo VII y durante 800 años (que se dice pronto) y eran tan de aquí como los demás descendientes de invasores. No sé si sería correcto decirle extranjerismo a una palabra porque procede del árabe (antiguo) o del celta, pero entiendo lo que quieres decir. El genio del idioma va modificándose de forma continua y llega un momento en que es contrario en algún sentido al del pasado. Tal vez llegue un momento en que seamos unos retrógrados y unos nostálgicos.

Answer (score 2):

En general, si el extranjerismo se usa en España, la RAE lo valida o lo propone sin mucho problema. Ejemplos: [*azúcar glas*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JEaT8eR) (azúcar en polvo o impalpable), [*parquin*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=parquin) (estacionamiento). También prefiere extranjerismos crudos, si se usan en España, a los ya adaptados en otros países. Ejs.: [*salami*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X1MjvKq) por [salame](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X1M0hAa), [*yidis*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cC0P95H) (este ni siquiera del ídish, sino del inglés y mal transliterado (!)) por [ídish](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KugdqLx), etc...

---

*Una posdata, respondiendo al comentario de Carlos Alejo: En el último diccionario de la RAE (2014) se metieron cientos de extranjerismos, pero no como se escriben, sino como la RAE piensa que deben escribirse, tal vez en un intento de mantener el control (?) y prevenir adaptaciones naturales. No sé qué pasará con todo eso, si se revisará o quedará; no lo tuve en cuenta en mi respuesta. Teniéndolo en cuenta, pues sí, la respuesta es que la RAE acepta casi cualquier extranjerismo sin ningún problema (pero adaptado ortográficamente y muchas veces mal), y ni siquiera hace falta que éste tenga un éxito masivo sobre el término autóctono.*

Comment: Pero ejemplos como _bluyín_ ponen de manifiesto que la RAE también acepta sin problemas extranjerismos usados en países de América Latina, ¿no?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Completé la respuesta teniendo en cuenta tu comentario.

Comment: Gracias por tu edición, estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario, sobre todo con lo de que al parecer no es ni necesario que el término extranjero tenga ventaja sobre el autóctono.