# ¿Por qué "el chocolate" es el sujeto en la frase "me gusta el chocolate"?

Tags: gramática

Estaba tratando de aprender algo de japonés, y en este idioma usan partículas para "marcar" el sujeto, objeto directo, objeto indirecto, etc. cuando hablan. Tratando de preguntar por qué iba tal o cual partícula en la frase, empiezas a hacerte preguntas sobre el idioma español. En la frase
"Me gusta el chocolate" según dicen, "el chocolate" es el sujeto de la frase. ¿Por qué es el sujeto? ¿No soy yo el sujeto que gusta del chocolate, y el chocolate es el objeto directo? Más confusión aparece cuando traduces esta frase al inglés: "I like chocolate". Aquí claramente "yo" soy el sujeto de la frase. ¿Cómo es que en español entonces "el chocolate" es aquello que realiza la acción? No entiendo. ¿Alguien me podría explicar?

Comment: @こうにょ ya que estamos, tu nombre no parece significar nada en japonés, ¿debo entender que has transcrito al hiragana lo que yo creo que has transcrito?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Deberia ser 高如 pero como el nombre debe tener más de 2 caracteres

Comment: @こうにょ muy interesante. Si has conseguido encontrar una palabra que signifique todo eso en japonés, ¡enhorabuena! Lástima que su lectura suene tan mal en castellano... :-)

Comment: *chocolate* es el objeto. También se usa así para identificarlo en inglés por ejemplo.

Comment: @ustanak segun varios ejemplos que vi en internet de sitios de gramatica española, dicen que es el sujeto. Un ejemplo: http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vcodigo=43646

Answer (score 1):

No creo, en este caso, que recurrir a la posible traducción del inglés sea de ayuda.

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

> ¿No soy yo el sujeto que gusta del chocolate, y el chocolate es el objeto directo?

Gustar del chocolate es una de **dos** construcciones para el verbo ***gustar*** como verbo intransitivo. En este caso eres tú quien siente el placer por comer chocolate y eres tú el sujeto que realiza la acción. El chocolate es el complemento, y es introducido por ***de(l)***.

La otra construcción es:

> "...me gusta el chocolate."

El sujeto que realiza la acción es la causa del placer, es decir, el chocolate. Tú eres quien siente el placer y estás expresado por un complemento indirecto: ***me***.

Espero serte de ayuda.

Fuentes:

https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/gustar#cite_note-1

http://lema.rae.es/dpd/    (tipea "gustar" en la barra de búsqueda)

Comment: El verbo [_tipear_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZoqvKTb) podría ser perfectamente un candidato a responder a [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17248/12637).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Creo que no compite (directamente) con ningún término autóctono.