# ¿Durante cuántos años debe aparecer una palabra en textos escritos para que la RAE la recoja en el diccionario?

Tags: rae, extranjerismos, dle

Por pura casualidad, he encontrado una palabra que podría dar respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17248/12637) que hice hace tiempo, pero que no es así porque la RAE no la recoge en el diccionario. Todo empezó a raíz del siguiente texto (negritas mías):

> La condición necesaria para que se **intersequen** el eje AP y la arista CD en el punto P es que el valor de lambda así obtenido esté comprendido entre 0 y 1.

Me resultó raro el verbo *intersecarse*, ya que yo siempre he dicho *intersectarse*, así que al principio pensé que sería un error, pero después de unos cuantos meses aquí uno ya ha aprendido a buscar en el diccionario:

> **[intersecarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Lx2ACWO)**
>
> Del lat. intersecāre.
>
> 1. prnl. *Geom.* Dicho de dos líneas, dos superficies o dos sólidos: Cortarse o cruzarse entre sí.

Vamos, que el término viene desde el latín, y buscando en el [NTTLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) veo que está recogido desde 1787 en su forma *intersecar* y desde 1803 como *intersecarse*.

Sin embargo, aquí viene la incongruencia: en textos escritos (al menos en el último siglo) es mucho más usada la palabra *intersectar* que *intersecar*. Lo podemos ver [tanto en Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intersectar%2Cintersecar&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintersectar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintersecar%3B%2Cc0) como en el CREA y el CORDE:

```
Palabra         CREA  CORDE
---------------------------------
Intersectar     2     0
Intersecar      0     0
---------------------------------
Intersectarse   2     0
Intersecarse    0     0
---------------------------------
Intersectan     11    1 (en 1935)
Intersecan      1     4 (3 en siglo XVI y 1 en el XIX)
```

Resumiendo: la tendencia es muy clara a usar el verbo *intersectar*, debido muy probablemente al verbo inglés *intersect*, más que a usar el muy arraigado *intersecar*, y esta tendencia dura ya más de un siglo. Por tanto, ¿a qué espera la RAE para recoger *intersectar*? ¿Durante cuánto tiempo debe aparecer una palabra en textos escritos para que la RAE recoja su uso? ¿Está tratando de evitar deliberadamente el extranjerismo?

Nota: ni *intersectarse* ni *intersecarse* aparecen tampoco en el DPD, así que no tenemos posible explicación ni siquiera ahí.

---

Actualización: consultada la RAE, dice: "El verbo con tradición de uso desde el siglo XVI es «intersecar» (lat. «intersecare»). «Intersectar» es más moderno pero, en efecto, es más frecuente en el uso actual. Remitiremos la sugerencia al Instituto de Lexicografía." ([Tuit 1](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/790869295177883648)) ([Tuit 2](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/790869667149733892))

Comment: No es el caso de intersecar / intersectar, pero no creo que haya respuesta a cuantas veces ha de aparecer la palabra. Hay varios factores que influyen en la decisión, se trata de una moda pasajera? es una palabra derivada de un avance/aplicación tecnológica temporal?  Ha de ser un diccionario que permita buscar por aquellas palabras que aparecen en libros de los últimos siglos, así que deben estar bastante seguros tanto en su adición o supresión. Hay varios artículos de interés relacionados en la web de la RAE http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/como-se-hace-el-diccionario

Comment: @AlexBcn "Intersectar": no es una moda pasajera, no es derivada de avances tecnológicos, aparece desde hace un siglo, no está en el diccionario. "Tuitear", podría ser una moda pasajera, es derivada de avances tecnológicos, aparece desde hace pocos años, está en el diccionario. Fuck logic. :-) En todo caso, tu disertación no carece de razón y bien podría ser una respuesta, si te animas.

Comment: En el caso particular de _intersectar_, creo que no tendría mucho sentido que lo aceptaran: antes bien, tendrían que preguntar por qué se dice _intersectar_ si se habla de rectas _secantes_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quizás ésta no sea la respuesta más ortodoxa y completa, pero fue la respuesta del académico Don Arturo Pérez-Reverte a la misma pregunta formulada en Twitter:

> Juαn Vte. Sαntαcreu: hola, buenas noches @perezreverte por favor,
>   ¿cuantos años hace falta que una palabra circule para que la RAE la
>   admita?
>
> Arturo Pérez-Reverte: @JVSantacreu Cinco, si hay documentación
>   escrita. Si es usada por los hispanoahablantes (50 millones aquí, 400
>   allí) de foma general.

Fuente: https://twitter.com/JVSantacreu/status/308294515494645760

Es decir, que la academia sí se toma un tiempo para, supongo yo, evaluar la evolución, aceptación y uso del término nuevo. Es una buen método para no añadir al diccionario cualquier palabra. Posiblemente, cinco años sea un estándar temporal que aplican para la evolución de un idioma, pese a la sensación de inmediatez que vivimos hoy en día.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si lo dice Pérez-Reverte, que es un académico numerario de la RAE, va a misa. ¡Gracias por preocuparte por responder a esta pregunta, aunque tenga ya su tiempo!

Comment: ¡De nada, para eso estamos! :) La verdad es que me quedé con la duda yo también, de casualidad descubrí este tuit del señor Reverte y no pude menos que postearlo aquí.