# Is "google" a verb in Spanish?

Tags: pronunciación, conjugación, extranjerismos

Is *google* a verb in Spanish?

If it is, how can I conjugate it? *Googlear* sounds really weird.

Is it pronounced differently too?

Comment: Creo que sabrás si lo *Googleas*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Googlear* does not appear in the dictionary of the Real Academia Española, but it follows the common pattern to create nouns. That is, to add a suffix on the form *-ear* for verbs in this case.

We pronounce it */gu.gle'ar/* and it has the common conjugation:

```
yo              googleo
tú              googleas
él/ella/usted   googlea

nosotros        googleamos
vosotros        googleáis
ellos/ustedes   googlean
```

From the article in Fundéu [*guglear*](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/guglear-1670/):

> En español pueden formarse derivados de nombres propios extranjeros con la adición de una terminación adecuada (como «washingtoniano» de Washington).
>
> De manera que «googlear» no es incorrecto, aunque si se llega a aceptar como parte del léxico castellano no debería haber problema en adaptar su escritura a «guglear». Sin embargo, una buena alternativa es «consultar en Google».

So if it is ever included in the dictionary, it may be on the form *guglear* instead of *googlear*.

More generally, it is difficult to tell if a word is "incorrect" or not. Apart from the ortographic rules, new words appear all the time and they are in a kind of *limbo*. If society decides that it is worth using them and consistently do, they may end up being accepted by the official dictionary, since in the end it intends to be a reflection of the words society uses.

Worth reading: [¿Durante cuántos años debe aparecer una palabra en textos escritos para que la RAE la recoja en el diccionario?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18511/1674)

Comment: I've been known to tell people sententiously: "No preguntes si no lo gugleaste antes." :)

Comment: @pablodf76 and I have to admit I had to _guglear_ a bit to answer this question :D

Comment: Actually, the suffix in this case is *-ear* rather than just *-ar*.  Also @fedorqui I'll do a quick write up on pronunciation formatting on meta in a  bit

Comment: @fedorqui also I screwed up on my pronunciation guide haha, it's definitely /gu.gle'ar/, the GL is of course a perfectly valid onset cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Googlear no es un verbo de manera oficial, de manera que no aparecerá en la Real Academia Española (RAE).

Sin embargo es comúnmente usado entre nosotros. Imagino que para que sea aceptado de manera oficial deben pasar cierta cantidad de años y algunos filtros.