# ¿Son "it", "fun" y "oc" palabras en español?

Tags: significado, palabras-raras

He estado jugando el juego de móvil *Words with Friends* desde hace unos meses. Ya me sé de memoria muchas de las palabras cortas que se aceptan, pero hay algunas que no sé por qué son aceptables.

No he podido encontrar una recopilación de palabras de 2 y 3 letras con sus significados. Estoy buscando algo parecido a [2 letter words](https://www.absp.org.uk/words/study2lw.shtml), pero en español.

Existe [Palabras válidas de 2 y 3 letras aceptadas por la última edición del Diccionario de la Real Academia](http://www.scrabbel.org.uy/ayuda/dos_y_tres_letras.htm), pero no te da los significados y creo que no coincide siempre con las palabras válidas en *Words with Friends*.

Una de mis contrincantes se quejaba de que yo había puesto una palabra inglesa, “it”, que no debía valer. En el juego de móvil no pasa nada, siempre puedo responder que si el juego lo acepta tiene que ser válida. Pero me gustaría saber realmente por qué se acepta.

A veces ni buscando en el diccionario encuentro la respuesta (bueno, wordreference.com, no sé la última vez que abrí un diccionario de los que pesan). Éste es el caso de “it”.

---

Me gustaría saber por qué se aceptan las siguientes palabras: *it*, *fun* y *oc*. Y por qué no se aceptan estas: *ad*, *aj* y *ax*, a pesar de aparecer en el DRAE. ¿Es posible que el juego esté mal y debería aceptar, por ejemplo, *ad*? Entiendo que es un vocablo latín pero se supone que ya entra dentro del vocabulario español como cuando hablamos de un "argumento ad hominem".

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! No tengo claro cuál es tu duda. ¿Quieres saber si "it" es una palabra válida en español? ¿O quieres disponer de una lista completa de palabras cortas en español? Nótese que, según las reglas de este sitio, la primera pregunta es aceptable mientras que la segunda no, ya que nuestras reglas contraindican las preguntas que piden recursos generales de cualquier tipo, aunque sean sobre el idioma español. Por tanto, por favor acláranos cuál es tu duda concreta para que podamos ayudarte lo mejor que podamos.

Comment: Bueno, lo ideal sería un recurso que abarque todas las palabras cortas, pero si esto no se puede, puedo buscar ejemplos de los últimos partidos. Tendré en cuenta esta regla para futuras preguntas. De todas formas los recursos online del DRE han podido resolver algunas dudas.

Me gustaría saber por qué se aceptan: it, fun y oc.
 Y por qué no se aceptan: ad, aj y ax a pesar de aparecer en el DRE.
(sé que no tienen que saber específicamente sobre este juego, pero por si alguien sabe cuál es la explicación más probable)

Comment: En la pregunta "Resources for learning Spanish", de nuestro sitio meta y enlazada en la página principal a la derecha, hemos subido recientemente listas de palabras del español. Puedes descargarlas y filtrar las de dos o tres letras, según te convenga. Sobre tu duda sobre palabras concretas, edita la pregunta para reflejar exactamente las palabras que constituyen tu duda.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos.

Comment: En [Words With Friends Rulebook](https://zyngasupport.helpshift.com/a/words-with-friends/?l=en&s=game-guides&f=words-with-friends-rulebook-1488949904) se lee: _Words With Friends uses the Oxford Spanish word lists. It includes Castellano as well as other varieties of American Spanish_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dice fedorqui, el juego usa un diccionario diferente al de la RAE. Para saber por qué se admiten esas palabras, tendremos que consultar ese diccionario y ver qué definición ofrece para dichas palabras. De momento, consultando tanto el diccionario de la RAE como el de americanismos de la ASALE, podemos ver que:

- *it* no viene en ninguno de los dos.
- *fun* no viene en el de la RAE pero [sí en el de la ASALE](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=fun). En El Salvador significa *teléfono* y en Puerto Rico se usa como anglicismo con su significado de "alegría, entretenimiento".
- *oc* [viene en el de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QqOm5CV) haciendo alusión a la locución *lengua de oc*, que vendría a referirse al idioma occitano.

Con respecto a tus otras dudas:

- *ad* está [marcada como en desuso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0gW1LAE) por la RAE. Por eso, aunque aparece en este es posible que el de Oxford no la recoja por arcaica. Existe también la voz *ad-* como prefijo, pero dudo que los prefijos sean válidos en el juego.
- *aj* significa "achaque", pero está marcado como que se usa principalmente en plural ("ajes"), y tal vez por eso el de Oxford no la recoja así.
- *ax*, lo mismo que con *ad*, está [marcada como en desuso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4b0jNyn) en sus dos acepciones.

Ten en cuenta que si el juego sigue un diccionario concreto, este no tiene por qué coincidir con el de la RAE, dado que ambos están realizados por entidades diferentes, y cada una sigue su propio criterio para saber qué debe incluirse como perteneciente al idioma y qué no.

Veamos cómo define el diccionario de Oxford las palabras que solicitas:

- en el caso de "it", si buscas en el *Oxford Spanish Dictionary* [la palabra *it*](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/it), te redirige a *post-it*, y de ahí a [*pósit*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TnfXVsj), que sí viene en el DLE. Por tanto, es posible que el juego te acepte *it* porque considere la palabra como parte de la expresión *post-it*, que sí la tiene como válida.
- en el caso de *fun*, [dice que es un acortamiento de *funboard*](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/fun), que es una modalidad de windsurf.
- en el caso de *oc, [coincide con la RAE](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definicion/oc) en que se refiere a la lengua de oc.

Recordemos que la RAE tiene como criterio el que la palabra [aparezca en textos escritos durante al menos cinco años](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18511/12637). Igual el de Oxford admite palabras de la expresión oral para poder reflejar los cambios del lenguaje más rápidamente. Ignoro cuáles serán sus criterios exactos, en todo caso.

Comment: Esta respuesta me da pie a comentar algo en mi opinión importante: cuando una palabra aparece en el diccionario de la RAE, pero marcada como *en desuso*, esa palabra NO está aceptada por la Academia. Sigue apareciendo en el diccionario con fines históricos (puede ayudar a entender textos antiguos), pero se considera que la palabra no es parte del español en la actualidad.

Comment: @Gorpik la verdad es que puede ser un debate interesante. ¿Qué se define como "idioma español"? ¿Únicamente el hablado en la actualidad, o todo lo que se ha considerado como perteneciente al idioma desde su origen? Habría que diferenciar entre "español actual" y "español" a secas. Y por tanto que una palabra no pertenezca al español actual no quiere decir que no pertenezca al español. Yo creo que una palabra en desuso sí la acepta la Academia, si no, no saldría en el diccionario. Solo está diciendo que hoy día no se usa.

Comment: Y ahí nos iríamos a intentar definir qué significa *aceptar* :) Yo me refería a todo ese aluvión de indignados porque la RAE *acepta* palabras como *almóndiga* o *cocreta*. En realidad, la segunda no sale en el diccionario y la primera sí, pero marcada como en desuso. Eso significa que la RAE no considera correcto su uso en la actualidad; e esto me refería con *aceptar*.

Comment: @Gorpik totalmente de acuerdo, entonces. Lo de la _cocreta_ y la _almóndiga_ me hace mucha gracia, ya he visto a muchos indignados, como dices, por el tema. Ciertamente, podemos decir que la RAE recoge muchas voces en el diccionario, correspondientes al español desde su origen, pero no todos se aceptan en el español actual al haber quedado en desuso.

Comment: Especialmente gracioso resulta cuando el quejoso dice que *la Academia ya no sabe qué inventar*; pero, en realidad, esas palabras de las que se queja (*toballa*, *murciégalo*...) son más antiguas que las usadas en la actualidad, que proceden de errores de pronunciación que acabaron generalizándose. El lenguaje evoluciona.